# How to Transform CSS only top left shapes of div

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I have a design that must be reshaped like the image below without having to change the letters such as using "transform: skew", because it will change the shape of the existing letters.

[image]

I dont know the name of this shapes and trying to search but the solution using skew or border transparent, and i trying by myself but the result not like what i want, please help.

Comment: You can shape with clip-path, add this in your shape css .  clip-path: polygon(0 8%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

Comment: You can get more shapes here on this editor. https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from @JamesAllan using clip-path like this

```
clip-path: polygon(0 21%, 100% 2%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

and this web [Bennettfeely](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy) help me so much to make other shapes, thank you so much.